# Robot That Worked in Gazebo 2 Fails to Launch in Gazebo 4

Tags: gazebo-4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Related to this question (http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7292/debug-messages-in-gazebo-4/). I have a robot that previously worked in Gazebo 2 on a different computer that I've been trying to port over to Gazebo 4. For some reason, every time I try to click on the name of the model under the "Insert" tab, Gazebo just exits without any errors or warnings. It was not like this for some of my simpler models or the models that were provided by default in the Gazebo model database. I've checked over the .sdf and .config files but can't find anything wrong with it. I've attached the .sdf file below just in case anyone is interested.
[model.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1414092333774534.sdf)

Here is the code for the .config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model>
  <name>Mesh Robot</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <sdf version="1.5">model.sdf</sdf>
  <author>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <email>john.doe@example.com</email>
  </author>
  <description>
    Insert description here.
  </description>
</model>
```

The only changes I made after downloading the files onto the computer with Gazebo 4 was that I changed  version tags from 1.4 to 1.5. The meshes referenced are saved exactly in the folder I wanted. I honesly have no clue what else to do at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE: When I ran Gazebo in verbose mode, I got the following warning.

```
[Wrn] [ColladaLoader.cc:1361] Polylist input semantic: 'COLOR' is currentlynot supported
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7293/robot-that-worked-in-gazebo-2-fails-to-launch-in-gazebo-4/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-10-27**:
The error message is in the Collada (*.dae) mesh loader. Perhaps that's where the problem is? The Collada code also changed a bit from 2.2 to 4.0 (search for Collada in [the Changelog](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/Changelog.md)).

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-27**:
I'm not sure what I'm trying to look for, but seems like nothing was done to the Collada loader from version 1.9.6 until 4.0.0. The weird thing is that Blender 2.72 (the latest version) doesn't have a problem importing my model and showing it. Another issue is that the .dae file I'm using is too large to change with gedit. Would it be a good idea for me to downgrade to Gazebo 3 for the time being?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-10-28**:
Are you able to post the meshes so we can try to reproduce the problem? If there are multiple meshes, try posting the smallest one.

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-28**:
Is there an email account I can send the .rar archive to?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-10-28**:
It's easiest if you can provide a mesh publicly. Are there any small meshes that you can provide that reproduce the problem with compromising anything you want to keep secret?

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-28**:
I'm not worried about confidential information, actually. The problem is more along the lines of me not being able to upload the .rar archive the meshes are stored in for some reason.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-10-28**:
Can you put it in a dropbox public folder and share the link?

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-28**:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6px1m6agv4nj8fq/meshes.rar?dl=0

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-29**:
Any luck so far?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-10-29**:
I can confirm that the meshes load in meshlab, but not in gazebo4. I'm going to add this to the gazebo issue tracker.

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-29**:
Would it be a good idea for me to downgrade to Gazebo 3 for the time being?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-10-29**:
I didn't test gazebo3, since I didn't have it on my system, but gazebo3 is worth a shot, since I think most of the Collada changes happened in gazebo4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've posted this as an [issue on the gazebo issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1319/potential-regression-in-colladaloader-in).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-29**:
Thank you.

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-11-11**:
I noticed that another user marked the issue as solved with the relevant pull request about an hour ago. How long would it be before the change is rolled out? I just re-installed ros-indigo-gazebo4-ros-pkgs again, and it still had the same issue.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2014-11-11**:
current release gazebo 4.0.2 does not contain this patch, see https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo_4.0/Changelog.md for details. We'll make a release soon with the latest patches for gazebo 4.0.3.

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-11-14**:
I know that Player has a SVN version (3.1.0) that's contains the latest patches. Is there an equivalent in Gazebo, or do I have to wait?